# Custom Tree Node search algorithm in java

Tags: java, java-stream

I am trying to search the child nodes based on the search query. I also need to keep their parents in the list. I am facing difficulty iterating and filtering the full tree that has been populated with parents and children.
The search query will match against the nodeName property of the following class.

**This is my TreeNode class**

```
public class TreeNodeDTO {

/** The id. */
private String id;

/** The nodeName. */
private String nodeName;

/** The children. */
private List<TreeNodeDTO> children;

//setters and getters
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example of a search query ? And what did you tried so far ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a helper method that returns a `Stream<TreeNodeDTO>` of this node and its descendants (searched recursively) and then search on the stream:

```
private Stream<TreeNodeDTO> descendants() {
    return Stream.concat(
        Stream.of(this),
        children.stream().flatMap(TreeNodeDTO::descendants));
}
```

Usage:

```
Optional<TreeNodeDTO> maybeNode = rootNode.descendants()
    .filter(n -> n.nodeName.equals("something"))
    .findFirst();

maybeNode.ifPresent(n -> /* do something with the found node */);
```

---

**EDIT 1:**

If you want to retrieve many nodes that satisfy your search criteria, you can do it this way:

```
List<TreeNodeDTO> results = rootNode.descendants()
    .filter(n -> n.nodeName.equals("something"))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

---

**EDIT 2:**

To find the parent nodes of the nodes that satisfy your search criteria, consider adding a `getParent()` method in your `TreeNodeDTO` class that returns the parent node. Then you could use it as follows:

```
List<TreeNodeDTO> parents = rootNode.descendants()
    .filter(n -> n.nodeName.equals("something"))
    .map(TreeNodeDTO::getParent)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you tweak a little bit more so that it only filter the searched items keeping their parents while removing other nodes?